# Query database by date, month, year

Tags: sql-server-2008, query

How can I query order by date.

Like this:

[image]

And the same for week, month, year...?

Comment: What is your table structure like?  You need to make it very clear what your data looks like, and what your desired results are.  right now it's not clear at all.  You can edit your question to add that info in.

Comment: i have just updated the questions. I just need a statistics report

Comment: Well you still don't show what your actual data looks like, so I'll have to guess.

Comment: -1 as this looks like a basic homework questions that a simple google search will answer (or a basic knowledge of sql)

Comment: I need a report to show many orders in database last 30 days. Ex: 02/22/2012 -> 132 orders, 02/21/2012 -> 81 orders... etc. Just show date, total orders of that day. That's all

Comment: @vNext I posted an answer, but normally you should show what you have tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without sample data I need to guess, but you want aggregations.

For Days:

```
SELECT CAST(OrderDate as DATE), as 'Date'
       COUNT(*) as 'Orders', 
       SUM(OrderPaidAmt) as 'TotalAmpunt'
FROM OrderTable
GROUP BY CAST(OrderDate as DATE)
```

For weeks or months, you need to do aggregation on `DATEPART` output:

```
SELECT DATEPART(WEEK, OrderDate) as 'Week',
       COUNT(*) as 'Orders', 
       SUM(OrderPaidAmt) as 'TotalAmpunt'
FROM OrderTable
WHERE YEAR(Orderdate) = YEAR(GETDATE())
GROUP BY CAST(OrderDate as DATE)
```

I added the `WHERE` clause in the second one to only show from this year. If you want to see multiple years  you need to `GROUP BY` the `YEAR()` value of your orderdate as well.

Comment: For days, how can I get last 30 days? not all days!

Comment: Add a `WHERE` filter - `WHERE OrderDate > DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE())`

Comment: Also you're welcome.  You realize people who answer your question are just people on the internet who aren't getting paid or anything, right?